# Efficiency of nested lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda

Here's a program where `main` has two lambdas defined. `a` calls `b`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto b = []() { std::cout << "b" << std::endl; };
    auto a = [&]() { b(); };

    a();
}
```

Now, since `b` is only used by `a`, it can also be defined inside `a`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    auto a = []() 
    { 
        auto b = []() { std::cout << "b" << std::endl; };

        b(); 
    };

    a();

}
```

My question is this: Let's suppose `a` is called repeatedly in a loop and so there are efficiency concerns. Can most compilers be expected to make the b-inside-a version as efficient as the b-outside-a version?

Comment: _"there are efficiency concerns"_ Such as? According to what? Why are you worrying about "efficiency" before you have profiled and found a performance problem?

Comment: why do you think b-inside-a version is more efficient than b-outside-a version?

Comment: Why ask about something you can just [try out yourself](https://goo.gl/wLmEPt)?

Comment: @XiaotianPei Or, indeed, the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better than that; both programs will be identical to:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
}
```